# kubernetes RBAC : allow to scale deployments upto 6 replicas

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, scaling, rbac

I have implemented RBAC in my project. Given permission to scale deployment but there is no upper limit to scale and it is getting misused. People are scaling deployments to 15, 20 pods. Is there any way to restrict them from scaling and allowing to scale upto certain maximum limit ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. We will give permission at API call not on the resource.We can solve your problem by setting pod quota for specific namespace.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/quota-pod-namespace/